# SUMMARIZECOLUMNS handling multiple columns with the same name

Tags: powerbi, dax

For debugging purpose I want to create a DAX table using `SUMMERIZECOLUMNS` fuction which selects the same column names of two different tables.

```
Tab = SUMMERIZECOLUMNS ( Sales[Product_ID], Product[Product_ID] )
```

It raises an error:

> The Column with the name of 'Product_ID' already exists in the 'Tab'
> Table

Replacing `Product[Product_ID]` with: `SELECTCOLUMNS( Product, Product[Product_ID] )` does not solve the problem as it produces error:

> A single value for column 'Product[Product_ID]' in table 'Product'
> cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to
> a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation
> such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Comment: try with:

evaluate
SUMMARIZE('Sales', 'Sales'[Prod_id], 'Product'[Prod_id])

Comment: The problem stays the same. You cannot have 2 columns of the same name in a table. So the column needs a new name.

Comment: try:

evaluate

selectcolumns(
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
'Sales'[Prod_id]
,'Product'[Prod_id]
,"KEY1", SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Prod_id])
,"KEY2", SELECTEDVALUE('Sales'[Prod_id])
),"Key1",[KEY1]
,"key2", [KEY2]
)

add some measure if you dont want a cartesian join as output from summarize

Comment: @msta42a It turns out that there is a simpler way, without SELECTEDVALUE. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle renaming the same column names of different tables with SUMMARIZE. With SELECTCOLUMNS we can refer to both table and column.

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Sales,
        Sales[Product_ID],
        Product[Product_ID]
    ),
    "Col1", Sales[Product_ID],
    "Col2", Product[Product_ID]
)
```